# List all values from one column based on value from another column

Tags: r

I have a large spreadsheet with data that lists vendor lot of materials associated with a certain manufacturing batch. I want to be able to output all of the manufacturing batches associated with each vendor lot for all of the materials. Here is a short example of what I have, and then what output I would like. The real spreadsheet is hundreds of columns with around 100 rows, otherwise I would just it manually.

```
df <- data.frame("MFG Batch" = c("20A", "20B", "19A","20C", "20D"), "Material 1 lot" = c("X1", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X1"), "Material 2 lot" = c("Y1", "Y1", "Y2", "Y1", "Y3"))
```

The output I want would just be a list or table that would look something like this:

> Material 1 lot 
>   X1: 20A, 20B, 20D 
>   X2: 19A, 20C 
>   
>   Material 2 lot 
>   Y1: 20A, 20B, 20C 
>   Y2: 19A 
>   Y3: 20D

I'm not that concerned about the format of the output as long as I can delineate what each 'material' is and have each 'material lot' and a list of what 'MFG batches' are associated with each 'material lot'. I would like it in a list form, though, if possible.

Sorry, I am fairly new to R, so if I need to expand on this or improve my question please let me know. Thanks!

Edit: Here is additional information and what I would like to see as the output:

Here is what I used to generate the below table (I just repeated it manually for each column and compiled them together

```
    df <- data.frame("MFG Batch" = c("20A", "20B", "19A","20C", "20D", "20E", "20F", "20F", "20G"), "Material 1 lot" = c("X1", "X1", "X2", "X2", "X1", "X3", "X2","X3", "X4"), "Material 2 lot" = c("Y1", "Y1", "Y2", "Y1", "Y3","Y3","Y3",NA,"Y4"), "Material 3 lot" = c("Z1", "Z1", "Z2", "Z1", "Z1","Z1","Z1",NA,"Z2"))
setDT(df)
    df[ , .(material = colnames(df[,3]), associated_values = list(sort(unique(MFG.Batch)))), by = df[,3]]
   Material.2.lot       material associated_values
1:             Y1 Material.2.lot       20A,20B,20C
2:             Y2 Material.2.lot               19A
3:             Y3 Material.2.lot       20D,20E,20F
4:           <NA> Material.2.lot               20F
5:             Y4 Material.2.lot               20G
> df[ , .(material = colnames(df[,2]), associated_values = list(sort(unique(MFG.Batch)))), by = df[,2]]
   Material.1.lot       material associated_values
1:             X1 Material.1.lot       20A,20B,20D
2:             X2 Material.1.lot       19A,20C,20F
3:             X3 Material.1.lot           20E,20F
4:             X4 Material.1.lot               20G
> df[ , .(material = colnames(df[,4]), associated_values = list(sort(unique(MFG.Batch)))), by = df[,4]]
   Material.3.lot       material       associated_values
1:             Z1 Material.3.lot 20A,20B,20C,20D,20E,20F
2:             Z2 Material.3.lot                 19A,20G
3:           <NA> Material.3.lot                     20F
```

The output I want would just be a list or table that would look something like this using some sort of loop so I don't have to manually do this for 400 columns, 
 which will be growing regularly:

```
              lot       material       associated_values
1:             X1 Material.1.lot             20A,20B,20D
2:             X2 Material.1.lot             19A,20C,20F
3:             X3 Material.1.lot                 20E,20F
4:             X4 Material.1.lot                     20G
5:             Y1 Material.2.lot             20A,20B,20C
6:             Y2 Material.2.lot                     19A
7:             Y3 Material.2.lot             20D,20E,20F
8:           <NA> Material.2.lot                     20F
9:             Y4 Material.2.lot                     20G
10:            Z1 Material.3.lot 20A,20B,20C,20D,20E,20F
11:            Z2 Material.3.lot                 19A,20G
12:          <NA> Material.3.lot                     20F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea is to `group` your table by two different columns (`Material.1.lot` and `Material.2.lot`), and then `aggregate` the `MFG.Batch` column in some way from there.

Everything will be similar to this -- it depends on what you want as output / what looks most natural to you.

Here is an extremely basic way of doing it from `base` R. Here, the way of aggregation is `list` -- all `MFG.Batch` values associated with each unique `Material.[1,2].lot` value are collapsed into an associated list.

```
tapply(df$MFG.Batch, df$Material.1.lot, list)
# $X1
# [1] 20A 20B 20D
# Levels: 19A 20A 20B 20C 20D
# 
# $X2
# [1] 19A 20C
# Levels: 19A 20A 20B 20C 20D
tapply(df$MFG.Batch, df$Material.2.lot, list)
# $Y1
# [1] 20A 20B 20C
# Levels: 19A 20A 20B 20C 20D
# 
# $Y2
# [1] 19A
# Levels: 19A 20A 20B 20C 20D
# 
# $Y3
# [1] 20D
# Levels: 19A 20A 20B 20C 20D
```

Personally, I might do this in `data.table` where your output is still a `data.table` (i.e., similar to the input):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[ , .(associated_values = list(MFG.Batch)), by = Material.1.lot]
#    Material.1.lot associated_values
# 1:             X1       20A,20B,20D
# 2:             X2           19A,20C
df[ , .(associated_values = list(MFG.Batch)), by = Material.2.lot]
#    Material.2.lot associated_values
# 1:             Y1       20A,20B,20C
# 2:             Y2               19A
# 3:             Y3               20D
```

Again the values are captured as a `list` -- more specifically, a "list column" where each row of the column is a list.

this route also makes it slightly "prettier" to deal with non-unique values (none are present in your sample data set), as well as to potentially sort them:

```
df[ , .(associated_values = list(sort(unique(MFG.Batch)))), by = Material.1.lot]
#    Material.1.lot associated_values
# 1:             X1       20A,20B,20D
# 2:             X2           19A,20C
```

And so on.

`data.table` also lends itself quite naturally to a more general approach with `melt` to apply this to potentially many columns at once. On your sample data the following works:

```
df[ , melt(.SD, id.vars = 'MFG.Batch', variable.name = 'material')
    ][ , .(associated_values = list(MFG.Batch)), by = .(material, value)]
#          material value associated_values
# 1: Material.1.lot    X1       20A,20B,20D
# 2: Material.1.lot    X2           19A,20C
# 3: Material.2.lot    Y1       20A,20B,20C
# 4: Material.2.lot    Y2               19A
# 5: Material.2.lot    Y3               20D
```

The first step is to reshape your table wide-to-long by putting the `Material.[1,2].lot` columns under one column (named `material`).

With this "melted"/long table, you can do the aggregation of all columns in one step, similar to the above, but also grouping by the "new" `material` column.

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there a way to repeat this automatically for a few hundred columns?

Comment: Sure. Again it depends on your desired output, but both approaches in the answer are amenable to loops. In the first example, you can loop over column indices and replace `df$Material.1.lot` with `df[[column_index]]`. In the `data.table` example you can loop over column names and use `by = column_j`

Comment: Sorry to keep asking, but would you be able to append your response with a way to loop it? I thought I could do it on my own, but I cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: it would help if you could edit your example to have a few more representative columns

Comment: Thank you, I will update it and also add an output that I was able to make for one column

Comment: I updated it with what I would like to see as an output from the loop. Thanks!

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you again

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution is to use `lapply`+ `unstack`, i.e.,

```
res <- setNames(lapply(seq(ncol(df))[-1], function(k) unstack(df[c(1,k)])),names(df)[-1])
```

such that

```
> res
$Material.1.lot
$Material.1.lot$X1
[1] "20A" "20B" "20D"

$Material.1.lot$X2
[1] "19A" "20C"


$Material.2.lot
$Material.2.lot$Y1
[1] "20A" "20B" "20C"

$Material.2.lot$Y2
[1] "19A"

$Material.2.lot$Y3
[1] "20D"
```